# Is it possible to have optional values in mixins?

Tags: less, mixins, optional-parameters

With optional I mean really optional, i.e. without a default fallback value.

```
.fontEMSmall(@color: "", @weight: 300) {
  font-weight: @weight; color: @color;
  font-size: 0.875em;  line-height: 140%;
}
```

I want to be able to use `.fontEMSmall()` without having to specify color (it works with `color: ""` but it is not valid CSS).. i.e. something like

```
.fontEMSmall(@color: "", @weight: 300) {
  if(@color) color: @color;
  font-weight: @weight; 
  font-size: 0.875em;  line-height: 140%;
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Mixin Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) and [CSS Guards](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature), e.g.:

```
.fontEMSmall(@color: -, @weight: 300) {
    & when (iscolor(@color)) {color: @color}
    font-weight: @weight; 
    font-size:   0.875em;  
    line-height: 140%;
}
```